# Excel formula to find the X nearest combination of values to a certain value combination

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, we have 3 columns with values in them Length, Width, and Height of objects. Each row stands for 1 object, now we need to find the X number of objects that fit the most together.

For Example:

[image: Example table Excel picture]

Now let's say we need the 2 closest sets of values, the output should give Nbr. 1 and 2 because [abs(11-10) + abs(9-8) + abs(4-5)] is the smallest value you'll get. Here we needed to find the 2 closest but sometimes we need to find the 25 closest sets of values.

Moreover, some might find Height not important or really important so you may want to lower or heighten its importance by adding in factors F(1,2,3) with which you multiply a part of the formula:

```
[F1 * abs(11-10) + F2 * abs(9-8) + F3 * abs(4-5)]
```

I tried to find the first (second, third and so on) smallest difference in value which works for just one variable but not multiple ones at the same time with:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$5002,MATCH(SMALL(ABS(B$2:B$5002-B2),2),ABS(B$2:B$5002-B2),0))
```

I don´t know an Excel formula to solve this problem as I want to find the X nearest combination of values.

I expect a result showing the row numbers of X objects that fit the best together.

Comment: Yes pretty tricky to do by formula to say the least. You could develop a 2d array like this array formula to find the distance of the closest pair (assuming data in a2:c4), but you still need to find which pair it is that's closest =MIN(IF(ROW(A2:A4)<>TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A4)),ABS(A2:A4-TRANSPOSE(A2:A4))+ABS(B2:B4-TRANSPOSE(B2:B4))+ABS(C2:C4-TRANSPOSE(C2:C4))))

Answer (score 0):

I Created a VBA Excel code that seems to work pretty nice in finding out which value combinations fit best together. It shows the closest values and the sum of all differences to determine the combination that works best. I did remove the first row of the picture in the description though. If anyone can improve, please do.

```
Sub test()

Dim last_row As Long   
    last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim m As Integer

Dim L As Integer
Dim W As Integer
Dim H As Integer
Dim AantalGelijken As Integer

Dim FL As Integer
Dim FW As Integer
Dim FH As Integer

FL = 1
FW = 1
FH = 0.8

AantalGelijken = InputBox("How many comparable sets do you need", "Number")

L = 2
W = 3
H = 4

For i = 1 To last_row
    For j = 1 To last_row
        If i <> j Then
            Cells(j, 5).Value = FL * Abs(Cells(i, L) - Cells(j, L)) + FW * Abs(Cells(i, W) - Cells(j, W)) + FH * Abs(Cells(i, H) - Cells(j, H))
        End If
    Next j

        For k = 1 To AantalGelijken
            Cells(i, 5 + k) = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A1:A9999"), WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Small(Range("E1:E9999"), k), Range("E1:E9999"), 0))
            Cells(i, AantalGelijken + 6) = Cells(i, AantalGelijken + 6) + WorksheetFunction.Small(Range("E1:E9999"), k)
        Next k



    Range("E1:E9999").Clear

Next i


End Sub
```

`